# finding sub-matrix K in an interaction matrix that most closely resembles a diagonal

Tags: python, matrix, algebra

I have a math problem I am trying to solve in Python.

I have a 2D interaction or [design structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_structure_matrix) matrix M of size n x n. The off-diagonal elements, E_ij or E_ji, correspond to the level of interaction, or dependency, between i and j, like the following (n=4, note that E_ij doesn't necessarily equal E_ji):

```
array([[1.        , 0.84329654, 0.20122157, 0.77170836],
       [0.13859503, 1.        , 0.60849155, 0.75713354],
       [0.08269742, 0.2694153 , 1.        , 0.81393679],
       [0.89496009, 0.32028813, 0.0307102 , 1.        ]])
```

I would like to find a subset matrix K containing elements k < n, which minimizes such off-diagonal values. In other words, I would like to find a subset matrix K in M that most closely resembles a diagonal matrix. In the subset matrix K, the row indices should be the same as the column indices, but not necessarily consecutive.

So for the example of the array given above, if k = 2, then we have a total of 6 possible sub-matrices (e.g. 4 choose 2), and the optimal sub-matrix for me would be (i = 0, j = 2):

```
[[1.         0.20122157]
[0.08269742 1.        ]]
```

Right now, my solution is brute force, and so for large values of (n choose k, it becomes really slow. Here is my solution so far:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from operator import itemgetter

n = matrix.shape[0] # size of original matrix
k = 2
sub = combinations(range(0, n), k) 
sub = list(sub) # list of all possible index combinations


# populate all possible sub-matrices
sub_matrices = []
for comb_idxs in sub:
    sub_val = matrix[np.ix_(comb_idxs, comb_idxs)]
    sub_matrices.append(sub_val) 


# make an off-diagonal mask
inv_eye = np.ones([k, k])
np.fill_diagonal(inv_eye, 0)

# apply mask to sub-matrices and sum their off-diagonal values
off_diag_sub_matrices = sub_matrices*inv_eye
off_diag_sum = np.sum(np.sum(off_diag_sub_matrices, axis=1), axis=1)

# find the index of the sub-matrix with minimal off-diagonal sum  
min_idx = min(enumerate(off_diag_sum), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Any ideas on how I might make this algorithm more efficient?

Comment: Can you add some sample matrices to illustrate more clearly on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hey, @asimo thanks. just added examples and code i have so far.